# Redirect for non-www to www not working for https

Tags: nginx, redirect, amazon-route53, elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to redirect all non-www requests to www with my nginx server, but despite successfully redirecting the http request (http://example.com to https://www.example.com), the https request gets hung up. I have read where the browser tries to read the ssl certificate before the redirect and due to this, the hang up can occur, but I recently created a new ssl certificate to include `example.com`, so I don't believe that should be an issue. Here are the details of my setup:

Route53, Elastic Beanstalk, Load Balancer, S3

- My Elastic Beanstalk instance is using a Classic Load Balancer with the SSL certificate attached.

[image: load-balancer-setup]

- SSL Certificate for www.example.com (primary), example.com, .example.com

[image: ssl-certificates]

- S3 set to redirect non-www requests to www

[image: s3-redirect]

- DNS configured for example.com to point to the s3-bucket redirect

[image: dns-configuration]

- Nginx config to force https

> ```
> files:
> "/tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh":
> owner: root
> group: root
> mode: "000644"
> content: |
> #! /bin/bash
>
> CONFIGURED=`grep -c "return 301 https" /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`
>
> if [ $CONFIGURED = 0 ]
> then
> sed -i '/listen 8080;/a \ if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }\n'
> ```
>
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
>       logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules added"
>       exit 0
>       else
>       logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules already set"
>       exit 0
>       fi
>
> ```
> container_commands:
> 00_appdeploy_rewrite_hook:
> command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact
> 01_configdeploy_rewrite_hook:
> command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact
> 02_rewrite_hook_perms:
> command: chmod 755 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
> ```
>
> /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
>       03_rewrite_hook_ownership:
>       command: chown root:users /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh

Comment: What does "gets hung up" mean? This isn't really a sensible description of a problem or error. Exactly what is happening? [What is your domain name?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)

Comment: Hung up as in the server took too long to respond and times out after a long request. Is there additional information that would be helpful in providing support?